# Regex in Notepad - Keeping text after a double space and removing the double space

Tags: regex, notepad++

In Notepad++ using regular expressions (Regex) I want to get this:

```
/*M 2  */  r1
```

to this, without any spaces in front of it. There's a double space after the "/" for reference:

```
r1
```

So far using ".+(/  )" under Find with "\1" as replace returns a result like this:

```
/  r1
```

(No spaces in front of the resulting r1).

What exactly is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're currently *capturing* the slash and space in a group, and replacing with that group. Instead, try matching everything to the left of the `*/`, including the `*/` and spaces to the right, and then replace with the empty string, which will result in only the `r1`.

Find:

```
.+\*\/ +
```

and replace with the empty string.